# How to duplicate multiple of the same .mp4 video in notepad

Tags: video, notepad

in notepad, I am just playing around with spamming things and i was trying to make multiple of the same .mp4 video pop up at the same time but only 1 would pop up at any given stage. How could I have multiple of the same .mp4 video pop up? Here's my notepad code for the .bat file:

```
@echo off
SETCONSOLE /minimize
:loop
start  tai.mp4
timeout 1
start tai.mp4
goto loop
```

Comment: The player you are using would have to support multiple instances of the player. If you are using VLC Player take a look at this: https://www.vlchelp.com/enable-disable-multiple-instances/

Comment: thanks! that worked out a treat. However could you please write this as an answer so I can mark you as the answer and upvote you? I appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player you are using would have to support multiple instances of the player. If you are using VLC Player take a look at this: vlchelp.com/enable-disable-multiple-instances

Comment: thankyou so much!